# html5 audio not play next song

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have html5 code like this

```
<audio controls autoplay>
   <source src="song/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   <source src="song/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   <source src="song/3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

why it's play only lastest song `3.mp3` ? How i can give it auto play all song `1.mp2->2.mp3->3.mp3`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate tag for each audio

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="song/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio controls>
  <source src="song/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio controls>
  <source src="song/3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

or create a playlist control like this  https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-audio-player-with-playlist/